# How is the "dr" param suppose to work on Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have an issue with the GA /collect endpoint:

https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?cid=1234&t=pageview&dp=%2Fblog&v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&aip=1&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

Where:

- cid = 1234
- t = pageview
- dp = /blog
- v = 1
- tid = UA-XXXXXX-1 (replaced by my own)
- aip = 1
- dr = https://google.com

The `/debug` endpoint gives me `"valid": true,`

Everything works fine (I see the events on GA) except the `dr` param, I can't find any trace of it.

I don't have any referral exclusion on the property.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong, and how can I get the `dr` param working?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dr` parameter is `document referrer` used by Analytics to detect the source / medium. So in your case the hit will be attributed to the `Organic Search` channel.

I tried it:

[image]

Comment: But, according to this doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr I'm supposed to be allowed to manually set this referrer right?

Comment: Yes, see my answer now, I updated it with a screenshot :)

Comment: But this is the source, not the referrer 
And the referrer should be `https://google.com` or whatever I set, not just "organic search"

Comment: You said that you can't find any trace of parameter dr... the trace is this. Also the source and medium are 'google / organic' and Full referrer is 'google'. If you want to see the URL like you want, probably you have to use a solution like this: https://www.analyticstraps.com/ricerche-non-tracciate-da-google-search-box/

Comment: It's not that I want to see the full url, I just want to know what I can set to see the referrer in the `acquisition > all trafic > referral sites` section. Which was the purpose of the `dr` param from my understanding 

Comment: You will not find 'google.com' in referrals unless it is identified as Referral traffic.

Comment: Okay I think I get it, they only use the referrer header to display that information, I'm not really sure what the `dr` is for but..

Thank you for your time Michele, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome :) any way from documentation: 'Specifies which referral source brought traffic to a website. This value is also used to compute the traffic source.'